# Are there states where voting is not anonymous?

Tags: voting

Anonymity is one of the desirable requirements of voting process in elections. Are there states where voting is not anonymous i.e. who voted whom is public?

Comment: US States, or "states" as in countries?

Comment: @T.E.D. Or Mexican or German or Indian or Australian states?  I suspect that any such state, or indeed a state in the sense of "country," would suffice as an answer to this question.

Comment: Worth noting, not *all* voting is desired to be anonymous.  We like to say that it is desirable for the public to be able to vote in anonymity, but some votes, such as those cast be electors in the US electoral college, are explicitly public by design.

Comment: @phoog - Well, its a pretty simple answer, but *which* pretty simple answer depends on what was meant by "states".

Comment: @CortAmmon I'm not sure your example holds. Accountability reduces the viability of faithlessness, which if it wasn't desired could be removed entirely.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt Which implies that not all elections are trying to achieve the same set of desired outcomes.  There's also many reasons behind each tweak we do to the voting process.  For example, not only does the accountability reduce the viability of faithlessness, but it also makes the process of ratifying the vote *far* easier because there's no need to obscure the information being ratified.

Comment: I can't tell you which states, but I can tell you the election results. 99.99% for the government party...

Comment: Non-private ballots were the norm until the late 19th century. Most votes in a partisan caucus are not cast by secret ballot, at least in Colorado.

Comment: If historical examples are allowed, I think Prussia had an open ballot (and 3 clasees) voting system between 1850 and 1918.

Comment: Of course, but most of those you probably wouldn't consider very democratic (or any at all).

Answer (score 8):

It seems that Nigeria uses an [open ballot system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_ballot_system) in order to minimize potential for election fraud.

As @CortAmmon states in the comments above, public voting is desirable in some cases. For example, in a representative democracy, it is important for constituents to be able to audit the votes of their representatives, to make sure the representative is faithfully representing the constituents' interests.

Answer (score 1):

The Swiss Cantons of Apenzell and Glaris have a system where people vote in public, in the open air in front of everyone. The german name for that is *Landsgemeinde*, which translates roughtly in "Land's community".